# Getting access denied after a successfull authentication Spring Security with JDBC

Tags: authentication, jdbc, spring-security, access-denied, spring-4

After a successful authentication i get redirected to a access denied page.

**WebSecurityContext**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityContext extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/admin/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasAnyRole("ROLE_ADMIN", "ROLE_CONTRIBUTOR","ROLE_ROOT")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/admin/login")
            .failureUrl("/admin/login/error")
            .successHandler(new SuccessfulAuthHandler())
            .loginProcessingUrl("/admin/login")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
            .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/admin/login/logout");
}

@Bean(name = "passwordencoder")
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(10);
}
```

**SuccessHandler**

```
 @Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException {

    final HttpSession currentSession = request.getSession();
    final User user = userService.findByUsername(authentication.getName());
    final List<Object> jObj = new ArrayList<>();
    final List<Institution> institutions = institutionService.findAllByUserID(user.getId());

    for(Institution i : institutions){
        Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("name", i.getName());
        m.put("id", i.getId());
        jObj.add(m);
    }

    currentSession.setAttribute("userInInstitution", jObj);
    currentSession.setAttribute("currentUser", user);

    String servlet = "";
    if(user.getRole() == ConstantsCommon.USER_ROLE_ADMIN){
        servlet = DashBoardController.URL;
        currentSession.setAttribute("dashboardServlet", servlet);
    }else{
        servlet = DashBoardController.URL;
        currentSession.setAttribute("dashboardServlet", servlet);
    }

    if(jObj.size() > 1){          
        currentSession.setAttribute("institution",institutions.get(0));
    }else{
        currentSession.setAttribute("institution",institutions.get(0));
    }

    RedirectStrategy r = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    r.sendRedirect(request,response, servlet);
}
```

**Login HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="pr-wrap">
            <div class="pass-reset">
                <label>
                    Enter the email you signed up with</label>
                <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="pass-reset-submit btn btn-success btn-sm" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <p class="form-title">Sign In</p>
            <form class="login" name="loginForm"  method='POST'>
                <input type="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
                <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" />
                <div class="remember-forgot">
                    <div th:if="${error}" class="alert alert-danger notificationMsg" role="alert">
                        <span th:text="${error}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div th:if="${msg}" class="alert alert-success notificationMsg" role="alert">
                        <span th:text="${msg}"></span>
                    </div>
                    <!--<div class=" forgot-pass-content">-->
                        <!--<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="forgot-pass">Forgot Password</a>-->
                    <!--</div>-->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong here ?????? The user im logging in with has the role "ROLE_ADMIN". One thing i have also noticed is that my success handler doesn't even get triggered which suggest that mu authentication isn't successful but that can't be right because the password and username are 100% correct.

Comment: Spring version 4.0.2; Url i'm calling is /admin/dashboard; Currently i get presenetd by the default 403 page generated by tomcat but i should be seeing any page in the /admin/* path

Comment: Did you send the CSRF token in your login page?

Comment: Yes i Have @dur

Comment: Show your `UserDetailsService`.